# Wordpress wp_nav_menu not displaying menu

Tags: wordpress, menu

I'm using the following code to display the menu on a site. Its a Network and it works on the Root site but when I create a new network it doesn't work

```
<?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'header-menu','menu_class'      => 'top-nav') ); ?>
```

The only thing it echos out is

```
class="last-menu-item menu-item-footer-main-container">
```

nothing else. Any idea what may be causing this?

edit: surrounding code

```
<div id="header">



<?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'header-menu','menu_class'      => 'top-nav') ); ?>

    </div><!-- end #header -->
```

surrounding output:

```
            <div id="header">
class="last-menu-item menu-item-header-menu-container"><ul id="menu-header-menu" class="top-nav"><li id="menu-item-7" class="first-menu-item menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page current-menu-item page_item page-item-5 current_page_item menu-item-7"><a href="#">...</a></li>
</ul></div>
```

Comment: I highly doubt thr line is the issue. Can we see some surrounding code please?

Comment: @ColeJohnson I just updated it with more context

Comment: @ColeJohnson I had only one item in my menu, added the second item it started working fine..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the fact that the closing tags are `</ul></div>` and your code outputs `<div id="header">class="..."><ul ...>`, I would suspect that just changing you code to be

```
<div id="header" <?php wp_nav_menu(array(...)); ?>
</div>
```

would fix the issue.